# Vlookup range with a defined variable

Tags: vba, excel, match, vlookup

I'm consolidating data from several excel files, I have 22 files to consolidate; however, I need to specifically look up for a cell value.

In my VBA code I declared a variable called file=int(1) and I'm doing a Loop to open and consolidate each excel file to a consolidated file. All of my excel files are numbered from 1 to 22.

What I want to to is Vlookup, but the range of the Vlookup I want it to have the stored value in file while doing the loop.

For example

```
file = Int(1)
Do Until file = 22

 ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($I$6,'[file.xls]Sheet1'!$B$4:$V$27,MATCH($F$26,'[file.xls]Sheet1'!$B$3:$V$27,0),FALSE),0)"

ActiveCell.Select
                Selection.Copy
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                ActiveCell.Select
                Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

                file = file + 1
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: so your file name are 1.xls, 2.xls, ..., 22.xls?

Comment: Yes :)Those are the names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice tidy little loop!  OK, I think I have an idea what you're trying to do here.  You want to have the `[file.xls]` in your formula update dynamically for each iteration of the loop.  Since you're using the `formula` property, which takes a string, you can concatenate your stored `file` value right into it.

This should do the trick.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($I$6,'[" & file & ".xls]Sheet1'!$B$4:$V$27,MATCH($F$26,'[" & file & ".xls]Sheet1'!$B$3:$V$27,0),FALSE),0)"
```

Hope I understood properly, if not, we'll go another round!

Comment: So the formula would be ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($I$6,'[& file & ".xls]Sheet1'!$B$4:$V$27,MATCH($F$26,'[& file & ".xls]Sheet1'!$B$3:$V$27,0),FALSE),0)" ? ?? ? ?

Comment: Close, looks like you're missing a few quotes.  Try this.

 `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($I$6,'[" &  file & ".xls]Sheet1'!$B$4:$V$27,MATCH($F$26,'[" & file & ".xls]Sheet1'!$B$3:$V$27,0),FALSE),0)"`

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much I got another question

Comment: I have all the 22 files open haha but I want to use the same method Windows(" " & file & ".xls").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close But excel is not compiling, you know if it has to do with the Windows.Activate method or my code is wrong?

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a space in front of your file name that way.  You don't need the first set of quotes or the &.  This should work.  `Windows(file & ".xls").Activate: ActiveWorkbook.Save: ActiveWindow.Close`